# Calculation of the power of a signal

Tags: integration, signal-processing

Suppose we want to calculate the [power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density#Power_spectral_density) of the signal $y(t) = m(t)\cos(\omega_c t)$, where $m(t)$ has zero mean, and the power of $m(t)$ is P watts.

It is easy to show that the power of $y(t)$ is $P/2$ by first calculating the [power spectral density (PSD)](http://www.commsp.ee.ic.ac.uk/~pld/Teaching/comms1_09/lecture_8.pdf) of $y(t)$ and then integrating it from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. However, if I go to the original definition of the power of a signal, I get stuck as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
P_y &= \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} y^2(t)dt\\
&=\lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} m^2(t)\cos^2(\omega_c t)dt\\
&=\lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} m^2(t)\left[\frac{1+\cos(2 \omega_c t)}{2}\right]dt\\
&=\frac{P}{2} + \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T/2}^{T/2} \frac{m^2(t)\cos(2 \omega_c t)}{2}dt\\
\end{align}
$$

I am unable to find any reason for the integral in the last line to be zero. Is there any reason that the integral has to be zero?

Comment: Suppose $m(t)=\cos(\omega_c t)$. Then $m$ has zero mean und $P=\frac{1}{2}$, but $y$ has power $\frac{3}{8}$.

Comment: @ccorn It is a very well-established result in communication books that the power of modulated signal is half that of the power of the signal. Please [see the second slide here](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee179/handouts/slide10.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}m^2(t)\cos(2\omega_c t)dt$$

is the DC value of the function $m^2(t)\cos(2\omega_c t)$. Assuming that $m(t)$ is a band limited low pass signal with a band edge $\omega_0<\omega_c$ (i.e., $m^2(t)$ has a band edge $2\omega_0<2\omega_c$), then the above DC term equals zero.

If $m(t)$ is not ideally band limited, the DC term of the modulated signal is very likely to be negligible, but the integral will not evaluate to (exactly) zero.

You can also determine the power spectrum of $y(t)$ to arrive at the same result. Let $M(\omega)$ be the power spectrum of $m(t)$:

$$M(\omega)=\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\left|\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}m(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt\right|^2$$

The power spectrum of $y(t)$ is

$$Y(\omega)=\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\left|\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}y(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt\right|^2=
\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\left|\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}m(t)\cos(\omega_c t)e^{-j\omega t}dt\right|^2=
\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\left|\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}m(t)\frac12 (e^{j\omega_ct}+e^{-j\omega_ct})e^{-j\omega t}dt\right|^2=
\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\frac14
\left|\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}m(t)e^{j\omega_ct}e^{-j\omega t}dt+
\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}m(t)e^{-j\omega_ct}e^{-j\omega t}dt\right|^2=
\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\frac14\left[
\left|\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}m(t)e^{j\omega_ct}e^{-j\omega t}dt\right|^2+
\left|\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}m(t)e^{-j\omega_ct}e^{-j\omega t}dt\right|^2+
2\Re\left\{\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}m(t)e^{j\omega_ct}e^{-j\omega t}dt\cdot
\int_{-T/2}^{T/2}m^*(t)e^{j\omega_ct}e^{j\omega t}dt\right\}
\right]=\\
\frac14\left[M(\omega-\omega_c)+M(\omega+\omega_c)\right]+
\frac12\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\Re\left\{\ldots\right\}$$

The power of $y(t)$ is obtained by integrating the power spectrum. Integrating the first term $\frac14\left[M(\omega-\omega_c)+M(\omega+\omega_c)\right]$ gives $P/2$, where $P$ is the power of $m(t)$. But there is also the last term which is generally non-zero. However, for almost all practical purposes this term can be neglected, because, as shown above, it depends on the spectral content of $m(t)$ at the modulation frequency $\omega_c$, which is usually either zero or negligibly small.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Can you please confirm that if we use the PSD method with $\omega_0 > \omega_c$, the result of $P/2$ doesn't hold, just like your explanation? In the book, I didn't find any such qualification for frequencies.

Comment: @ubaabd: Could you explain the "PSD method" in your question? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: The PSD of a signal $m(t)$ is $\lim_{T \to \infty}|M(f)|^2/T$, where $M(f)$ is the Fourier transform of $m(t)$. If we integrate the PSD function from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, we get the power of the signal. For a brief introduction, see [here](http://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece458/radha/ss07Keyur/Lab-Handouts/PSDESDetc.pdf).

Comment: @ubaabd: I know the definition of the PSD, but I'd like to know how exactly you showed that the term in question is zero via "the PSD method".

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} PSD df = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4}\left(M(f+f_c) + M(f-f_c) \right) = P/2$. There is no such integration that appears in this method.

Comment: The above-mentioned definition has $M_T(f)$, instead of $M(f)$, where $M_T(f)$ is the Fourier transform of truncated $m(t)$.

Comment: @ubaabd: It doesn't work like that. If you use the definition of the PSD with the truncated Fourier transform and the limit, you don't get the expression with the two shifted spectra of $m(t)$.

Comment: @ubaabd: I added the computation of the power spectrum of $y(t)$, showing that it is not simply the sum of two shifted versions of the power spectrum of $m(t)$. So the power of $y(t)$ is generally not exactly equal to $P/2$.

Answer (score 0):

You chose the wrong bounds of integration. Rather than integrating across $[-\frac{T}{2},\frac{T}{2}]$, integrate across $[0,T]$. This will give a non-zero value. The choice of bounds shouldn't matter, but it does because of the way the integral will account for the negative component of the signal.

Comment: In $m^2(t)$, there is no negative component because of the squaring operation. I still don't understand why bounds should matter, as the definition should work in all conditions.